# What is this IP?

Tags: ip

Hi all I'm seeing this IP on Avast's network security search: 25.0.0.1. Is this IP local? Modem root IP is 192.168.1.1 . I search this IP it's saying this IP in England. What does it means?

Answer (score 1):

You can look up who owns an IP address [at RIPE](https://apps.db.ripe.net/search/query.html#resultsAnchor). As you can see, the whole IP block 25.0.0.0 to 25.255.255.255 is assigned to the UK Ministry of Defence.

However, the same IP block is used by the VPN network Hamachi to address hosts inside the Hamachi network. In that context, the IP address 25.0.0.1 is the DHCP server of the VPN. This use of an IP address space owned by someone else goes against common practices on the Internet and can cause all kinds of problems, including but not limited to confusing security software.

Regarding *why* that IP is appearing in your logs of Avast network security: You would have to provide more information about the context in which this IP address appears.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I think it is about Hamachi program, it's looking like DHPC.
[link](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/368104-dns-server-not-responding.html)

Comment: @emrece Hamachi was an important keyword: updated the answer.